# Увеличение времени запущенного settimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени! такой вопрос - можно ли увеличить значение запущенного таймера settimeout?

допустим в коде есть проверка переменной и если она равна false то запустить таймер если иначе то пролить время таймера

```
    var runtimeout;
        if (imrun == false) {
     runtimeout = setTimeout(function() { norun () }, 500);
        } else {
        //продлеваем значения таймера который я закрепиз за переменной runtimeout
        }
```

Comment: Отложить нельзя, можно проверить и запустить новый.

Comment: Как всегда самый интересный вопрос: "Зачем?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таймер нельзя продлить, но и задав таймер никакого процесса не идёт, функция таймера не вызывается до триггера по времени. Следовательно можно пересоздать таймер. Вот **пример** как можно создать динамичный таймер

```js
class dynamicTimer {

  constructor(func, delay) {
    this.callback = func
    this.triggerTime = +new Date + delay
    this.timer = 0
    this.updateTimer()
  }

  updateTimer() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer)
    let delay = this.triggerTime - new Date
    console.log("Current delay: ", delay)
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.callback, delay)
    return this
  }

  addTime(delay) {
    this.triggerTime += delay
    this.updateTimer()
    return this
  }
}

let timer = new dynamicTimer(function() {
  console.log("2+2 =", 2 + 2)
}, 50) // Должно сработать почти мгновенно

timer.addTime(1000) // Но мы продлим ещё на секунду
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var runtimeout = null;
if (imrun) {
  //продлеваем значения таймера
  clearTimeout(runtimeout); 
}
runtimeout = setTimeout(function() { norun(); }, 500);
```

Comment: Чего-то тут не хватает

Comment: @tutankhamun "- Чего в этом супе не хватает?  - Хлеба!" Г.Хазанов. Все тут есть. По крайней мере, все, что есть в коде вопроса.

Comment: Хотя да. Пересмотрел еще раз. Вы правы